# Android Studio - Open epub + pdf files from default directory application (Programmatically)

Tags: android, pdf, epub, android-studio-3.0

How to open  default file manager app that let you choose a file but only with extension `.epub` or `.pdf` programatically via Intent?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with answering your own question, but you're going about it wrong. You have to post your question in the *question* section and post your answer in the *answer* section. Here you posted both in the question section.

Comment: I have edit the answer to fit it as a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code shown is the declaration of the intent that you have to start for opening the default file manager app that let you choose a file but only with extension `.epub` or `.pdf`, I hope it will be useful.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
intent.setType("application/epub+zip");
String[] mimetypes = {"application/epub+zip", "application/pdf"};
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimetypes);
startActivityForResult(intent,PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE);
```

It is a mix of solutions I found that work so maybe it is redundant. Let me know what you think!